# RDS, 2012 Connection Broker and 20008R2 Session Hosts

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, rds

I'm trying to install a new RDS-farm with session hosts in 2008R2 and the connection broker with 2012 and I can't find any information at all on this.

Servers:

RDCB01, Connection Broker and Session Host roles installed.

RDSH01-16, Session host role installed.

On the connection broker I created a new collection under "Remote desktop services", I then added all my session hosts to local group "RDS Endpoint Servers".

On RDSH01-16 I have added the session hosts to the farm with the collection name i created on RDCB01.

In the DNS i have added collection.domain.com to all RDSH and the RDCB.

In 2008R2 you can set the connection broker to "farm redirection" so the users never get logged on there, but I can't find this in 2012. The only thing I can find is under Remote Desktop Services -> Collections and host servers where I can set allow/don't allow new connections, if I set "don't allow" when the users try to logon to collection.domain.com once in a while they still try to logon to rdcb01 and get an error message saying "no new connections is allowed.."

How do I set the RDCB to "dedicated farm redirection"?
Is it even possible to have 2008R2 session hosts with a 2012 connection broker?

Answer (score 1):

Your connection broker should not be in collection.domain.com, only the session hosts should be. The session hosts talk to the session broker, not the clients.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.  There isn't a Session Brokers Computer group and apparently it is just not possible. I myself have not had a definitive answer on this from Microsoft, but no one else can get it to work.

2008 = 2008
2012 = 2012
2008 x 2012

I too had this same problem.

Comment: Likewise, I've been struggling for several hours to add 2012 to a 2008 server farm or vice versa and there seems to be no way to make this happen